# 2001 Hyundai Santa Fe power steering leak

Tags: hyundai, power-steering, power, santa-fe

Where is the power steering return hose on a Hyundai Santa Fe? Is there a diagram somewhere that shows how it is run?

Comment: Is the Sante Fe 2wd or 4wd? Which engine? I don't know for sure if this really matters, but it may. Also, you should be able to easily find the return line. There are two lines which should be going to your power steering pump. One would be the high pressure side going out to the steering rack. It will have pressure fittings on it. The return side is low pressure and will be attached to the pump via a hose clamp. An alternative to this would be if there is a separate reservoir from the pump. Here, the return line should be towards the top of the reservoir and feed towards the bottom of it.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I couldn't find the return hose shown on any of the diagrams on Hyundai's free tech site (www.hyundaitechinfo.com) or in any of the system diagrams on any of the Hyundai part sites (e.g., www.hyundaipartsdepartment.com).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to easily find the return line. There are two lines which should be going to your power steering pump. One would be the high pressure side going out to the steering rack. It will have pressure fittings on it. The return side is low pressure and will be attached to the pump via a hose clamp. An alternative to this would be if there is a separate reservoir from the pump. Here, the return line should be towards the top of the reservoir and feed towards the bottom of it.